# validation flag failing in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am stuck on an issue, where a flag is not getting reset correctly.

I have the below code. I am writing this code specific to IE8. On blur of the fields, it iterates through the classes for a field and if any of the class validation returns false, it should display error and set `flag4=false`. Then on click of the submit button, it needs to check if all the flags are true, and if they are, return true.

But now, `on blur` is happening correctly. If any validations fail, it's displaying the error and later if we change the error to correct format, it displays green. But the `flag4` is always returning `false`. Since it's always returning false, the form never gets submitted successfully and the user cannot move to the next page. My question is, where should I reset the value of `flag4`?

I have tried many options but on click of the button it fails. Once `flag4=false`, it is not becoming true even after giving all the fields correctly.

```
var flag4 = true;
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 8.0") != -1) {
    var firsttime=false;
    var validators = {
        fn1: function(val) {
            //return true or false;
        },
        fn2: function(val) {
            //return true or false;
        }
    };

    $('#submit_form :input').not('#id1,#id2,#id3').blur(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var returnVal1 = true;
        input.next('div.error_text').remove();
        input.removeClass('highlight');
        // Get all the classes of the current input
        if(this.className) {
            var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
            for(var p in classes) {
                if(classes[p] in validators) {
                    returnVal1 = returnVal1 && validators[classes[p]] (input.val());
                }
            }
        }

        if(returnVal1 == false) {
            firsttime=true;
            $(this).removeClass('green');
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
            var $msg = $(this).attr('title');
            input.after('<div class="error_text">'+$msg+'/div>');
            flag4 = false; 
        }

        if(returnVal1 == true && firsttime == true) {
            input.addClass('green');
        }

    });
}

$('#submitbtn').click(function() {
    var flag1, flag2, flag3 = true;
    if(flag1 && flag2 && flag3 && flag4) {
        returnvalue = true;
    } else{
        returnvalue = false;
    }
    return returnvalue;
});
```

If any validation returns false when the user enters first time, `firsttime=true`. The second time a user enters a correct value, that field should become green. For that I am using `if(returnVal1 == true && firsttime == true)`

Comment: logging what you get with console.log()  might shed some light

Comment: I tried to alert(). But once the flag4 = false, it is not becoming true even after giving all the fields correctly.

Comment: The only place in your code where `flag4` gets set to `true` is where it is declared, and that line is only executed once. You need to set `flag4` back to `true` somewhere in your event handler(s), but if your blur handler can be called for multiple elements but only tests the current element how can those elements be sharing the same flag?

Comment: Yea..that is troubling me now..I am not able to set flag4=true. Any other way where I can handle multiple elements in blur event?

Answer (score 0):

Like @nnnnnn said in the comments, the only place that `flag4` is being set to `true` is in the variable declaration. But why not add it to the beginning of your `onblur` function, and then it will be set to `true` unless it's set to `false` by something else, i.e. there's an error and you set it to `false`.

```
$('#submit_form :input').not('#id1,#id2,#id3').blur(function() {
        flag4 = true;
        // ...
});
```

Comment: Hi Joshua. Thanks for your reply. But if I make flag4=true as you have mentioned                                            if(returnVal1 == false) {
    // ...
    flag4 = false;
} else {
    //...
    flag4 = true;
}                                                                    then if the first field validation is false and second field validation is true.Then it will go to the next page even thought the first field validation is not correct.. Hope you understood what I am trying to say

Comment: That may be an issue with how you are setting `returnVal1`. In that case, try out my first suggestion.

Comment: Hi Joshua..I tried to keep flag4=true below the blur function as you have told. Even then, if one first field is false and second field is true, it overwrites the flag4= false and always returns true irrespective of the errors.

Comment: Can you post a `jsFiddle` of your HTML and JS so we can better see what you're trying to accomplish? Also please post the HTML of your page in your question.

Comment: I attempted to run your fiddle and inspected the `flag4` value, but it is always returning `true`, even when I didn't enter anything into the input fields.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39817/discussion-between-user1049057-and-joshua-smock)